# Splitting string[] to ArrayList and Returning Values

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I'm having an issue splitting a string array into a List/ArrayList.  I realise this is basic stuff but I've looked at so many examples that I've now completely confused myself at what's happening (or not happening).

Some code snippets:

```
private String[] stringTempList;
private ArrayList<List<String>> arrayImageList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

My list is read from a webpage and is formatted in plain text like: **['One','Two','Three', etc ...]**

So, some lines to strip out the stuff I want/don't want (note - I've separated these out to help me follow the process through):

```
stringExtractedList = stringText.substring(stringText.indexOf("['") + 2,
                stringText.lastIndexOf("']"));    
stringTempList = stringExtractedList.split("','");
```

From what I can see the above works as expected (creating an array (stringTempList), splitting out each item where it sees `','`.

Where it's going wrong:

```
arrayImageList.add((List<String>) Arrays.asList(stringTempList));
```

I expect this line to take my array (stringTempList) and move the items into an ArrayList.  I was hoping to use code similar to `arrayImageList.get(i);` to access individual elements.

However, the code above seems to add all items to the first index in arrayImageList (list size is always 1).  Running some debug tests eg `Log.d("Test", arrayImageList.get(0));` returns the following:

```
[One,Two,Three,Four, etc...]
```

I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.  I think I've confused two different ideas here.

Comment: Did you check the exact result of the split(",")?

Comment: Not familiar with Java, but `private ArrayList<List<String>> arrayImageList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();` creates a list of lists. What you want is a list only. So pick either `ArrayList` or `List<String>`. At that point it is redundant to create a new list - so just take the result of `split` directly. Or convert it to the desired type (most likely creating a copy in that step)

Comment: Do you want to create lists of lists with parsed elements from the string?

arrayImageList.add((List<String>) Arrays.asList(stringTempList)); 
is not valid java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change arrayImageList to a list of strings:

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayImageList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add them using the addAll method:

```
arrayImageList.addAll((List<String>) Arrays.asList(stringTempList));
```

Comment: Thank you.  In my error correcting previous errors, I stumbled on the `ArrayList<List<String>>` solution which just confused me.  Simple solution here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `addAll()` instead of `add()`

You'll also want to declare

```
private List<String> arrayImageList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: No problem!  Does the reasoning behind this make sense to you?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.  I'm very new to Java (and OOP in general) so applying my previous coding knowledge doesn't always help.  In my research (trying to debug my issue) I found that an ArrayList is an implementation of a List. I also read that List should be used in preference of ArrayList where possible. In my case - initially I expected the array to be fixed length (so List would have done) but as I plan further - I suspect a non-fixed length list is going to be beneficial (eg removing broken image links).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `addAll`, not `add`.

Comment: Thanks.  I think part of the confusion was that `.add` seemed to be adding all the elements - just not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i got this "wrong the right way", and I'm not that familiar with java, but here are my thoughts:

Your "arrayImageList" object is an ArrayList of List's. When youre adding your stringTempList-object, that object is correctly stored at the first available index of your 'List-of-lists'. If you want to access the individual elements (strings) from your "arrayImageList", you either have to adress the second dimension (the list of the list) like this:

**arrayImageList.get(0).get(i)**  <- not entirely sure about java-syntax here, but you get the picture.

If on the other hand you dont need the extra dimension, just use ArrayList instead og ArrayList>.